# Prove that Every number divides 0 while the only number that 0 divides is itself.

Tags: proof-writing

this problem from An Inquiry-Based Introduction to Proofs v1. by Jim Hefferon

I has problem in the second part  that only 0 can divide 0 
I think it is interminate form and when put 0/0 in wolfram it shows it's undefined

Is book wrong or I miss something ?
and If the book is not wrong how I begin the proof ?

Comment: Check your definition for "divides."  The correct definition should not have anything to do with actual *division*.

Comment: @JMoravitz is it every integer n can be divided by itself?

Comment: although it is true that every integer $n$ is divisible by itself, that is a result of the definition, not a definition itself.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

We say for two integers $a$ and $b$ that "$a$ *divides* $b$" iff there exists some integer $k$ such that $b=a\cdot k$.

For example $3$ divides $12$ since $12=3\cdot 4$.

Furthermore, $3$ divides $0$ since $0=3\cdot 0$.

See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor).

> Upon searching for sources, apparently in some materials the definition above has the added stipulation that $k\neq 0$.  This stipulation was not in the definition I was taught and its inclusion would make the statement false, but that stipulation is not included in the book you got the problem from.  Using the definition then from your book which agrees with the above, the proof follows rather directly.

---

What happens if $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$?  Does there exist such a $k$?

What happens if $a=0$ and $b=0$?  Does there exist such a $k$?

What happens if $b=0$ and $a\neq 0$?  Does there exist such a $k$?

What does all of this imply in relation to your question?

Comment: Ok I got that  Thank you  ^ ^ I just think about only about actual division

Comment: @JMoravitz: AFAICS: for $0|0$ this seems to hinge on what *some* means in '*some* integer $k$ such that $b=a⋅k$'.  For every $a \neq 0$, where $a|b$ there is exactly one $k$ such that $b=a⋅k$ (including where $b=0$).  For $a=b=0$ there are an infinity of integers $k$ such that $0=0⋅k$'.  If the definition said '*an* integer $k$', or more strongly '*a single* integer $k$', that would rule out $0|0$.  The use of *some* in this context may may be a "clever" way to allow for $a=b=0$ -- granting that *some* stretches across $[1,\infty)$.  But if so, it's not a miracle of clarity, is it ?

Comment: @ChrisHall "*some*" in mathematics is always meant as "*at least one.*"  If we meant exactly one, we would have said so.  If we meant only finitely many, we would have said so.  In symbols... $a\mid b\iff (\exists k\in\Bbb Z)(ak=b)$.  See [Existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification).

Comment: @JMoravitz: so, yes, the definition allows for $0|b$, where $0|b \iff b=0$.  *[Given the strict meaning of __some__ as you say.]*  My point was that the definition would be clearer if it treated $0|b$ as the special case that it is.  I note that the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) you referenced starts by defining $m|n$ only for $m\neq 0$ -- which is consistent with the definition of the division algorithm.  The extension to $m=0$ is mentioned in passing, but not explicitly defined there.

Comment: I disagree that it is that special of a case.  In a deleted exchange below, BillDubuque said it well; Consider theorems from group theory and ring theory about the quotient ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and the statement that $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$, that is that $[x]=[y]$ iff $n\mid x-y$.  This works just as well for the quotient set $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ with the (*obvious*) statement that $x\equiv x\pmod{n}$ including when $n=0$ noting that $\Bbb Z/\{0\}$ is a perfectly valid quotient of rings (*even if trivial*).

Comment: @JMoravitz: OK, I admit knowing next to nothing about group theory (and an approximately equal amount of ring theory) so for all I know you make a convincing case that $0|b$ (in particular $0|0$) is not that special.  I give up.  FWIW: stipulating $k \neq 0$, as you say, denies $a|0$ -- at least for $a \neq 0$.  For $0|0$ there are infinitely many $k \neq 0$ which satisfy $0 = 0 \cdot k$, so perhaps $0|0$ is still allowed -- unless the stipulation excludes all possible $k$ if $k=0$ is one of them.